# SpringBoot JPA - Many To One relation mapped between User and UserStats, but when I get the User from Repo, has no UserStats entities?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a domain entity User, and because I needed to create 2 separate sets of stats for each user for competitive and non-competitive game, it has a OneToMany relation with UserStats and each User should contain 2 UserStat objects in a List userStats object.

However, when I call userRepo.findAllBy(SomeCondition) the returned List contains User objects but those User object don't contain the UserStat objects?

User Class:

```
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "user")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "username", unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String location;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserStats> userStats;
}
```

USER STATS CLASS:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "userStats")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserStats {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userStatsId;

    private Integer victories;
    private Integer draws;
    private Integer defeats;
private boolean isLeagueUserStats;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

UserService SignUp METHOD:

```
    public void signUpUser(User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));


        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);

        List<UserStats> userStatsList = new ArrayList<>();

        UserStats userStats = new UserStats(0, 0, 0,  false, savedUser);
        UserStats leagueUserStats = new UserStats(0, 0, 0, true, savedUser);

        userStatsRepository.save(userStats);
        userStatsRepository.save(leagueUserStats);

        userStatsList.add(userStats);
        userStatsList.add(leagueUserStats);

        user.setUserStats(userStatsList);

        User savedUser2 = userRepository.save(user);

}
```

How can I make it so that when I save a User entity it also save's it's contained UserStats? How can I make it so when you retrieve User objects from the repository that they contain userStats list?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because you need to add the cascade in order to let him save in cascade

`@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

and also, I am not sure if you are using a LAZY fetchType in purpose, but if at any point you have problems loading some data (I mean, if it is bringing to you just null data) it may be because of it, in that case you will have to use EAGER instead of LAZY

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response that's really helpful, think the fetch lazy was when I was experiencing issues with testing but labelling tests with @Transactional fixed that. That makes sense, should I still leave the 'mappedBy="user"' within the ManyToOne or replace it with yours? Thanks.

Comment: I added cascade as you said to both entities, and changed to eager fetch, however when I call userRepo.finaAll() the users still don't show any UserStats list? Thanks.

Comment: [{"id":1,"username":"ss","password":"$2a$10$GikQXV8R2s805d1qSdJ3g.WFCrxgFB1fqBhuSW.DWHmJCzloy3tTa","name":"Sam","email":null,"location":"London","bio":"adadadada", "totalGamesPlayed":0}]

Comment: because you are using @JsonIgnore

Comment: it is literally ignoring it

Comment: If I remove that bad things happen to tests, maybe it was on something else, but I will try to remove it, thanks.

Comment: I see why... add this:  @JsonIgnore @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

Comment: I mean, you are ignoring the wrong attribute, add json ignore to user inside the User stats, because if not i will be doing an infinite loop going into user then to users stats and so on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241143/discussion-between-devck-dc-and-joedev2).